# Unable to boot into Windows 10 on dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

When I set Windows as the first boot option in BIOS it boots into Windows normally, and the same goes for Linux. However when I set Ubuntu as the first option and try to choose Windows from boot menu but it won't boot. I tried boot repair but it didn't help. What should I do now?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "_it won't boot_" - what error message do you see ?

Comment: Are both installed in BIOS boot or both installed in UEFI boot mode? If Ubuntu in BIOS and Windows in UEFI, you get the type of issue you seem to have. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating the GRUB file?

Run the following:

- `sudo os-prober` (type `man os-prober` to see what it does, see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober) for more info);
- `sudo grub-update` (update the GRUB: you should see in the output both Ubuntu's and Windows' boot partitions);
- `sudo grub-install /dev/sda/` (Assuming your grub is installed at `/dev/sda`: change it accordingly)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. I've done that. I think that real problem is with windows boot manager. As soon as I installed Ubuntu (pick an option to install along windows), I was unable to boot into windows wia standard boot menu.

Comment: Hmm, how odd... I have had issues with Windows not being able to boot from Ubuntu's GRUB, but not like that. I suggest, if you can, you try fixing Window's boot partition. Once fixed, boot in Ubuntu using a live CD/DVD/USB and try to update the GRUB again. If Windows is not detected, then it is very likely an issue with Windows' boot partition. Here is a [link](https://neosmart.net/wiki/the-drive-where-windows-is-installed-is-locked/) that I use as a reference for repairing Windows' boot partition. Check out steps 4 and 5.

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue with another solution?

Comment: I've reinstalled everything so it's not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In UEFI boot options only recognizes the windows boot. You need to allow non-UEFI boot on BIOS and then select the partition that has the GRUB option.